# SolidJS: ! zlib: unexpected end of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, solid-js

I keep running into this error when attempting to create a solidjs app using `npx degit solidjs/templates/js my-app`. Current setup is zsh on Mac

Comment: I don't see how this is related to zsh and suggest to remove the _zsh_ tag from the question.

Answer (score 5):

Sorted out by deleting the `~/.degit` folder in my home directory.